# For $\alpha$ a generator of $F^{x}$ with $|F| = p^r,$ $[Z_p(\alpha):Z_p] = r.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

A proof I am reading states that $F = Z_p(\alpha)$ which I understand but concludes that the degree of the extension $[Z_p(\alpha):Z_p] = r.$ I don't understand why. What would be an example of an explicit basis that shows that $Z_p(\alpha)$ can be considered as a vector space of dimension $r$ over $Z_p?$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an algebraic field extension $K(a)$ of a field $K$
with degree $n$ then a $K$-basis of $K(a)$ is always given by
$1$, $a$, $a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}$.

Comment: I may be missing something here but do we know that $Z_p(\alpha)$ is algebraic over $Z_p?$

Comment: Finite degree extensions are always algebraic.

Comment: Hmm but why is $[Z_p(\alpha) : Z_p] = r?$

Comment: I presume because $r$ is the degree of the equation defining $\alpha$.

Comment: How do we get that from $\alpha$ is a generator of $F^{x}?$